# can I reference the results of an ArrayFormula recursively in Google Sheets?

Tags: recursion, google-sheets, sum, cumulative-sum, sumifs

Say I have a table of indeterminate height,  with numerical values in Columns A & B:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 73 | 23 |  |
| **2** | 11 | 58 |  |
| **3** | ... | ... |  |

If I wanted to calculate the sum of A+B for each row, I could populate all of the results with one formula: `=ArrayFormula(A:A+B:B)`.

I want to do something similar, but instead of adding **A1** to **B1** to find **C1**, I want to add **C1** + **B2** to find **C2**.

I'm wondering if it is possible for ArrayFormula to self-referentially, so I can use the previous result in the next iteration of the formula?

Achieving this with one formula is important in this case, because the table keeps getting longer (it's populated by a live data feed).

At very least, I'd greatly appreciate any help in thinking this through :)

[Here's a demo Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TFNio10L4QcPGL1mNe9HFWrITsf38piyqSp9-DsfiZo/edit?usp=sharing) you can edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's called `running total` or `cumulative sum`... use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B:B))<=
 SEQUENCE(1, COUNTA(B:B)))*{C1; B2:B}), 
 SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B:B), 1, 1, )), "offset 1", ))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! I found this great blog post which explains how to calculate running totals with MMULT https://web.archive.org/web/20220122154122/https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/running-total/